Using subsampling-scale-image-view how can I add a rotation gesture? (rotate the image using a two finger gesture)
I am currently developing a map app for a project and I want my map to be a large imageview. (No, using an already made mapview implementaion is not possible for this project)
To that end I needed to be able to drag the image around the screen, rotate it, zoom in with pinch, and double tap to zoom in and out.
I tried implementing all of those myself, but apart from draging the image on screen I was faced with minimal success. buggy and choppy results.
So I opted out to use a library, I chose subsampling-scale-image-view because it also has subsampling. But it doesn't have the rotation gesture already implemented so I had to add it myself. I used this answer as a guide, but faced a problem. While the image did visually rotate, it was not the image rotating, but the view. This causes the image itself when moved using the library to be cut off the view if it is rotated.
(imagine the image on an angle and when moved perpendicularly to where it's facing it clips out of existence on the threshhold of the view)
I tried increasing the view's size such that its width and hight are equal (to the hight of the screen).
I expected that this will make it so when it's rotated the whole view would still be on screen eliminating the cut off point, but it resulted in two things. Now the image take a whole lot longer to load which is a problem if I were to use a huge map in the future, and when it does load it loads super "zoomed in" (it's not really zoomed in, it's just seems that way because it tries to fill the whole view).
The XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapActivity"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navbar1"
        android:layout_width="410dp"
        android:layout_height="101dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navbar" />

    <com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview.SubsamplingScaleImageView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navbar1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Avtivity code
public class MapActivity extends BaseActivity implements RotationGestureDetector.OnRotationGestureListener, View.OnTouchListener {
    BottomNavigationView navbar;
    SubsamplingScaleImageView mapImage;
    private RotationGestureDetector mRotationDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });
        init();
        navbar.setOnItemSelectedListener(this::onOptionsItemSelected);
    }
    public void init(){
        navbar=findViewById(R.id.bottom_navbar1);
        mapImage = findViewById(R.id.map);
        mapImage.setOnTouchListener(this);
        mRotationDetector = new RotationGestureDetector(this);
        mapImage.setImage(ImageSource.resource(R.drawable.checkerboard));
        mapImage.setPanLimit(SubsamplingScaleImageView.PAN_LIMIT_OUTSIDE);
    }

    @Override
    public void OnRotation(RotationGestureDetector rotationDetector) {
        float angle = rotationDetector.getAngle();
        mapImage.setRotation(mapImage.getRotation() + (-angle));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        mRotationDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return false;
    }
}

(Base activity just handles the menu)
The class (taken from the answer mentioned)
public class RotationGestureDetector{
    private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;
    private float fX, fY, sX, sY;
    private int ptrID1, ptrID2;
    private float mAngle;

    private OnRotationGestureListener mListener;

    public float getAngle() {
        return mAngle;
    }

    public RotationGestureDetector(OnRotationGestureListener listener){
        mListener = listener;
        ptrID1 = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
        ptrID2 = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                ptrID1 = event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex());
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                ptrID2 = event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex());
                sX = event.getX(event.findPointerIndex(ptrID1));
                sY = event.getY(event.findPointerIndex(ptrID1));
                fX = event.getX(event.findPointerIndex(ptrID2));
                fY = event.getY(event.findPointerIndex(ptrID2));
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if(ptrID1 != INVALID_POINTER_ID && ptrID2 != INVALID_POINTER_ID){
                    float nfX, nfY, nsX, nsY;
                    nsX = event.getX(event.findPointerIndex(ptrID1));
                    nsY = event.getY(event.findPointerIndex(ptrID1));
                    nfX = event.getX(event.findPointerIndex(ptrID2));
                    nfY = event.getY(event.findPointerIndex(ptrID2));

                    mAngle = angleBetweenLines(fX, fY, sX, sY, nfX, nfY, nsX, nsY);

                    if (mListener != null) {
                        mListener.OnRotation(this);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                ptrID1 = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                ptrID2 = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                ptrID1 = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                ptrID2 = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private float angleBetweenLines (float fX, float fY, float sX, float sY, float nfX, float nfY, float nsX, float nsY)
    {
        float angle1 = (float) Math.atan2( (fY - sY), (fX - sX) );
        float angle2 = (float) Math.atan2( (nfY - nsY), (nfX - nsX) );

        float angle = ((float)Math.toDegrees(angle1 - angle2)) % 360;
        if (angle < -180.f) angle += 360.0f;
        if (angle > 180.f) angle -= 360.0f;
        return angle;
    }

    public static interface OnRotationGestureListener {
        public void OnRotation(RotationGestureDetector rotationDetector);
    }
}

